# ConcurrentModificationException while sending a message to all clients

Tags: java, server, concurrentmodification

I have a problem while iterating an ArrayList of Sockets. The purpose of the list is to send message to all clients when another one connects except the last one. I get ConcurrentModificationException and I don't know how to manage it. Please help!

Server program:

```
 public void start() {

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(10001);
        thread = new Thread(new MessageClient(listOfClients));
        thread.start();
        while (!isStopped) {
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        listOfClients.add(socket);
        synchronized (listOfClients) {
            listOfClients.notifyAll();
        }
        g.getTextArea().append(
            "Client number " + listOfClients.size()
                + " has connected.\n");
        threadClient = new Thread(new SerThread(socket, listOfClients));
        threadClient.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    }
```

Thread program (MessageClient):

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        for (Iterator<Socket> cl = listOfClients.iterator(); cl.hasNext();) {
        synchronized (listOfClients) {
            cur = cl.next();
            if (!cur.equals(listOfClients.get(listOfClients.size() - 1))) {
            try {
                System.out.println("dddddddd");
                ous = new PrintWriter(cur.getOutputStream());
                ous.println("Client " + listOfClients.size()
                    + " has connected.");
                ous.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                JOptionPane
                    .showMessageDialog(null,
                        "There was a problem getting your outputstream.");
            }
            try {
                System.out.println("ddd");
                listOfClients.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: paste the stack trace. Normally u get ConcurrentModificationException  when u try to modify a failsafe collection while iterating it. Check where you may be doing it, intentionally or otherwise.

Comment: @Nazgul

dddddddd
ddd
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:886)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:836)
 at com.omisoft.basic_java.networking_and_gui.task4.MessageClient.run(MessageClient.java:24)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

This is the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of this problem was just using `synchronizedList`. It automatically takes care of synchronization between the threads.

Answer (score 0):

You try to modificate your collection `listOfClients.add(socket)` in one Thread(in Server) while another Thread `MessageClient` is iterating over it.

Comment: Would you help me with some solution please? Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: Fill your listOfClients before  starting your thread with MessageClient

Comment: How can I fill it when I can have clients connecting at any time?

Comment: If you want to send information only for last added client pass Socket Object into your Runnable instead of listOfClients and then use PrintWriter